# Can't create dictionary from file because of new line character

Tags: python

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Mother Jane
Father Bob
Friends Ricky,Jack,Brian,Jordan, \
        Ricardo,Sonia,Blake
```

As you can see I have a new line character at the end of "Friends" first line.  When I want to parse this file to a dictionary It is giving me an error with my current code.

I have looked online for the solution and tried multiple things but nothing seems to work.

```
with open('./file.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

    dic = {}
    for line in content:
        line_items = line.strip().split()
        if len(line_items) <= 2:
            dic[line_items[0]] = line_items[1]
        else:
            dic[line_items[0]] = line_items[1:]
```

I would like to have a result which looks like this:

```
dict = {"Mother": "Jane", "Father": "Bob","Friends":[Ricky,Jack,Brian,Jordan,Ricardo,Sonia,Blake]
```

But instead I get an out of index error.

Comment: Is that the complete content of the file? Or are there following Mother/Father lines?

Comment: Also - is a backslash literally the last character on the line (eg it's a indication character of multiline things in multiple programming languages) or is it just that you've put it there for an example here? Everything seems like it's indentation based...

Comment: This is the complete file and it contains a backslash to indicate that the friends list continues on the next line.  Also I cannot simply remove the backslash because this file is being generated by a server query and it adds the backslash every time.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work. It collects multiple lines into a logical line and then processes that. It also doesn't read the entire file into memory.

```
from pprint import pprint, pformat

dic = {}
with open('./newline_file.txt') as f:
    lst = []
    for line in iter(f.readline, ''):
        line = line.strip()
        if line[-1] == '\\':  # Ends with backslash?
            lst.append(line[:-2])
            continue
        else:
            lst.append(line)
            logical_line = ''.join(lst)
            lst = []

        line_items = logical_line.split(' ')
        if len(line_items) == 2:
            if ',' in line_items[1]:
                dic[line_items[0]] = line_items[1].split(',')
            else:
                dic[line_items[0]] = line_items[1]

pprint(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'Father': 'Bob',
 'Friends': ['Ricky', 'Jack', 'Brian', 'Jordan', 'Ricardo', 'Sonia', 'Blake'],
 'Mother': 'Jane'}
```

Comment: It seems that friend should point to a list, but it's a good start and with the 2 other answers the full code is available...

Comment: B. Go: Oops...fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
import re
with open('file.txt') as f:
    c = f.read().strip()

#cleanup line breaks where comma is the last printable character
c = re.sub(r",\s+", ",", c)

final_dict = {}
for l in c.split("\n"):
    k,v = l.split()
    if "," in v:
        final_dict[k] = [x for x in v.split(",")]
    else:
        final_dict[k] = v

print(final_dict)
```

---

**Output:**

```
{'Mother': 'Jane', 'Father': 'Bob', 'Friends': ['Ricky', 'Jack', 'Brian', 'Jordan', 'Ricardo', 'Sonia', 'Blake']}
```

---

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/17b8)

Comment: comma is never the last character... \ is!

Comment: Updated to : `last printable character`, thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 0):

You could accumulate a lines with a continuation backslash and only process lines once they are complete:

```
dic = {}
continued = ""
for line in content:
    if "\\" in line:
        continued += line.split("\\")[0]
        continue
    key,value = (continued+line+" ").split(" ",1)
    continued = ""
    value     =  [v.strip() for v in value.strip().split(",") if v != ""]
    dic[key]  =  value[0] if len(value)==1 else value

print(dic) # {'Mother': 'Jane', 'Father': 'Bob', 'Friends': ['Ricky', 'Jack', 'Brian', 'Jordan', 'Ricardo', 'Sonia', 'Blake']}
```